# Why we don't use fillets while making buildings?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, structures

Why don't we use fillets when making buildings and houses (i.e why do we leave the edges sharp?)? Does stress concentration factor not matter in making structures?

I am talking about the building like this-->

[image: Building with sharp edges]

I know this edge is not `highly stress concentrated`(only the atmospheric pressure is acted on these edges, which is easily bearable by this building.) but assume the time of any natural disaster, at that time these type of edges would be more likely to fail.And making the edges round doesn't affect the cost much.I think.

NOW ANOTHER EXAMPLE.

[image: Stiars]

This is also stress concentrated.As we climb the stairs there will definitely some forces will act.

Comment: Can you provide some specific examples of where you think fillets are routinely omitted where they would be helpful? Think about what direction the forces are acting, and what the material is.

Comment: I am not a civil engineer so I don't know the technical terms for this. consider a bench which is made of concrete, as the people will sit on the bench, it may increase the stress concentration at the edge which may cause the failure of the structure.

Comment: While using the *fillets* there may decrease the *stress concentration* as well give comfort to the people.is'nt it .

Comment: Says who?  What materials?  What country?  I don't see any supersharp-edged beams around here.

Comment: I can see the sharp edges around me. material: concrete .country : India.Any other specification required?

Comment: A sharp free *edge* isn't associated with any stress concentration. Do you see any (1) sharp cracks (2) above you in a (3) load-bearing material not otherwise reinforced that (4) can't be blunted by material deformation and (5) are propagating? If not, then you've answered your own question. If so, you found a case where the designer should have added a fillet, and you should get to safety right away

Comment: To follow @Chemomechanics comment, you are starting from the premise that the use of 'fillets' at so-called 'sharp edges' (as pictured) will decrease the risk of crack initiation.  From experience I don't consider this to be generally valid (as you have pictured it) but in specific concrete load bearing elements it might be a consideration.  Nonetheless one of the fundamental purposes in adding reinforcement to structural concrete elements is to add ductility to the structure and to activate this ductility there must be cracking of the concrete.

Comment: Additionally your premise deals with load-related (natural disaster) cracking.  The issue of crack propagation and 'sharp edges' actually becomes much more of a concern during the construction stage in that crack propagation can occur due to early age thermal and drying effects.  It later can become an issue during thermal expansion and contraction of the structure - these are generally not load related risks (although there are exceptions).  In this case fracture toughness (crack resistance) can be increased by geometry and also by the characteristics of the materials.

Comment: With respect to the concrete material, reducing the heat-producing elements of the mixture (lowering the Portland cement content, for example), reducing the water content, reducing the mortar fraction by volume, increasing the stone by volume and introducing certain types of fibres are options that can improve fracture toughness.  From the design and construction perspective, eliminating sharp edges, optimising the size of continuously cast elements, and if necessary introducing crack control measures will also help to reduce undesirable cracking.

Comment: This crack risk reduction approach is more of an art than a science in that any mixture constituent optimisations must be done in such a way that the early age strength development to thermal/drying stresses will improve resistance to crack development.   This requires considerable practical experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is simply cost. The loads in structures such as benches (which you describe in comments under the question) are very low and such structures often have huge safety margins. These margins are not intentional for such trivial structures, but are a consequence of working with reinforced concrete.

Reinforced concrete requires some concrete cover to protect the steel reinforcement from oxidation. For structures under small loads such as benches, just this concrete cover around very light steel reinforcement is already far more than sufficient to withstand the loads.

Given this, stress concentrations are no issue: worst case, a bit of concrete around the edges will be chipped off, but the structure will still be more than capable of withstanding the load.

So fillets become an added construction cost: it's cheaper to build a simple rectangular cross-section than a filleted one. Comfort is not a primary concern.

Comment: Machine elements are also designed with fos(Safety margins as you say), then why we use fillets there.

Comment: Cost. Agree. @ShivamSingh Machine elements are not building elements. There's also a scale difference typically in machine elements versus construction elements. Machine elements are manufactured in a more controlled(read as: cost effective) environment and may be more optimized structurally therefore including fillets where necessary.

Comment: I somewhat agree with this, but any mathematical proof.

Comment: @ShivamSingh, proof of what? The reason isn't mathematical, but financial and (in the specific case of RC elements) due to material requirements. You are assuming the reason is more "formal" and "scientific" than it actually is.

Comment: Proof of the things that the forces on these sharp edges are less that is failure stress.And I'm sorry if it is being the unnecessary question for you. but I want to discuss it with some experts like you and other on this website.

Comment: Honestly @ShivamSingh, I'd argue that the existence of all those "sharp edges" around you is proof that the internal stresses are lower than the failure stress. After all, if that wasn't the case, you wouldn't see any sharp edges because the edges would have failed by now (which wouldn't mean the building/bench/whatever as a whole collapsed, but that the edges got chipped off).

Answer (score 1):

In general architecture there is a cost pressure towards standardisation and it is often cheaper to use standard parts which are easy to assemble, specify and transport.

There is also the fact that in architecture the crucial loads are often supporting the span of the roof so the big loads tend to be compression and thrust on the walls with pinned joints where fillets don't really add much.

Equally in steel framed buildings it is often cheaper to over-specify the sections used rather than optimise them.

Having said that there are certainly plenty  of example of architecture where material limited (eg stone) have produced extrmely elegant structurally optimised designs :

[image: Vaulted Ceiling]